# Joint investment

Tags: taxes, canada

I had a elderly friend put me on her investment as joint.  4 years later, after she got dementia, her son took her into the bank and had my name removed.  Will this have any effect on my income tax?

Comment: Do you normally get tax forms about this investment?  Did anyone give you any money?  How long ago was this?  What kind of investment is it?  What kind of tax effect worries you?   As a general rule, you usually only pay income on money given to you as income.  You don't mention any details about receiving money.

Comment: "*after she got dementia, her son took her into the bank and had my name removed*" That can be challenged, since the woman was not of sound mind when she signed the documents.